# EC2 Security Groups Inbound rules ignored

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, fedora

I have a Fedora instance with security groups attached that open all traffic to 0.0.0.0/0, and the only open ports on the instance itself is 22 and 80.  I cannot connect to the webserver in the instance, and a quick nMap on the public IP given gives me only ports 22 and 3389.  Logging into the instance and running nmap on localhost shows me 22 and 80.  How do I get the instance to have 80 open publicly?

Comment: Can you curl from the box? Please post screenshots or information about your configurations (security groups, ACL), operating system, and show curl / corresponding logs. I assume you have your internet gateway set up properly within your VPC, perhaps you could post screenshots of that as well.

Comment: If I curl localhost, webserver is accessed.  If I curl from inside the system the public ip, I still get nothing.  And all my settings for my VPC are correct and showing that it should be open for all to see.  I'm running Fedora 23 if that helps any.

Answer (score 0):

I rebooted the instance from the EC2 console panel, and that did the trick.  Don't know why it would make a difference if I rebooted from there or a reboot while logged in via ssh, but it worked.